# Date Stamp with INSERT query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am inserting data from table `tbl_login` to table `LoginHistory` with date stamp. But I am confused to add Date Stamp with query string.

My Code is:

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName FROM tbl_login WHERE Username = """ & Me.txt_username.Value & """ AND Password = """ & Me.txt_password.Value & """"

strSQL3 = "INSERT INTO LoginHistory (UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, LoginDate)" & strSQL2 & Now()

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tack on Now() after strSQL2 because that puts it after the FROM and WHERE clauses. Put it into strSQL2 statement. The SQL engine can evaluate Now() function. Can use a single apostrophe in place of double quotes as delimiter character.

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Now() AS CD FROM tbl_login WHERE Username = '" & Me.txt_username & "' AND Password = '" & Me.txt_password & "'"

strSQL3 = "INSERT INTO LoginHistory (UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, LoginDate)" & strSQL2

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL3
```

Why even duplicate UserName, FirstName, LastName into LoginHistory? Just save UserID and Now().

Comment: This was just for understanding, I will Save just UserID and LoginDate. Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather add `Now()` as a default value for your LoginDate field. This way you won't have to take care about that in any query.
I think it's always better to implement such thinks at the lowest level: the table definition, in this case.